# SQL INSERT INTO for first row only

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want all my strings to be inserted into the first row ONLY.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim intCounter As Integer

For intCounter = 1 To 30
    strSql = "INSERT INTO tblCat (" & intCounter & ") Values('" & strAddress & "');"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Next intCounter
```

**Note**: my `tblCat` column names are as follows: 1, 2, 3, 4...

**Note**: my `tblCat` is a blank table.

When I run this code it enters the first string into (row 1 column 1), the next string into (row 2 column 2), the next string into (row 3 column 3)...etc.

How do I make it so all the strings are entered into row 1 ONLY?

For example, first string into (row 1 column 1), the next string into (row 1 column 2), the next string into (row 1 column 3)...etc.

Comment: "How do I make it so all the strings are entered into row 1 ONLY?" - it's not clear why you have 30 INSERTs in that case. And you want all the data to go to the first of your 30 INSERTs?

Comment: Yes, this my sad attempt to concatenate a massive text field that has been separated into several records(same field all in separate rows). So my plan was to place each record in separate fields on the first row and then concatenate them all into one record within one field. Sound like update may be a better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use [ALTER](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) keyword to add a new column then you can use UPDATE keyword to SET value to this a new column instead of using INSERT keyword.

Comment: This is all my sad attempt to concatenate a massive text field that has been separated into several records(same field all in separate rows). So my plan was to place each record in separate fields on the first row and then concatenate them all into one record within one field. Sounds like UPDATE may be a better solution for this problem.